# access NSMutableArray(objective c) from swift viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I been stuck for days and I want to access and modify my already initialized NSMutableArray from the swift view controller.

**seq.m**

*init()*

> ```
> _sequence = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @(false),@(true),@(true), nil];
> ```

**seq.h**

> @property(nonatomic,strong,readwrite) NSMutableArray * _Nonnull sequence;

**viewController.swift**

> var audio3:seq?

*viewDidLoad()*

> audio3?.sequence = [true,false,true]
>
> print(audio3?.sequence)

**Bridging-header.h**

> *#import "seqTest.h"*

all I got is '**nil**' as result

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your code snippets, your `audio3` variable is not initialized.  Try `var audio3 : seq? = seq()` instead of `var audio3 : seq?`.

The way your original code is, the `audio3` variable is uninitialized, so the initializer `init()`, where the property `sequence` is set up, is never called for that variable.  You get a `nil` because `audio3` itself is `nil`.  You could verify that using code like this:

```
if let x = audio3
{
    print(x.sequence)
}
else{
    print ("x is not initialized")
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! you're a godsend